# Adding time trend variable in ddply function

Tags: r, plyr, trend

I am having difficulties adding a time trend variable within a ddply function,

Here is the simplified code:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
price <- c(1,2,3,2,1,0)

df <- data.frame(id, price)

price_trends <- ddply(df, ~id, summarise, 
      mean_price = mean(price), 
      sd_price = sd(price))
price_trends
```

Now I also want to include a time trend coefficient per id (i.e., price inclining for id 1, declining for id 2), but I am having difficulties to include it in the ddply function from above. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try with `dplyr`, `price_trends <- 
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(mean_price = mean(price), 
            sd_price = sd(price))
`

Comment: Extending @RonakShah's solution: `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(mean_price = mean(price), sd_price = sd(price), trend = sign(sum(diff(price))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
slope <- function(x) (tail(x,1)-x[1])/length(x)
price_trends <- ddply(df, ~id, summarise, 
                      mean_price = mean(price), 
                      sd_price = sd(price),
                      trend = price %>% slope() %>% round(0))
> price_trends
  id mean_price sd_price trend
1  1          2        1     1
2  2          1        1    -1
```

Note that you actually get the slope if you remove the last `round(0)`. Further, you can define any coefficient of interest via the function. You can also include the function directly inside `ddply` like so:

```
price_trends <- ddply(df, ~id, summarise, 
                      mean_price = mean(price), 
                      sd_price = sd(price),
                      trend = ((tail(price,1)-price[1])/length(price)) %>% round(0)
                      )
price_trends
```